# my .js files in vscode seem to have a windows sign next to it, instead of yellow js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm a newbie when I comes to JavaScript and it seemed to come out of nowhere now I cant write any JavaScript, doesn't recognise the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the bottom-right corner... You probably will see `Batch`. Click that and you will be able to select another language mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the vscode-icons extensios to your vscode.
Maybe it can solve that issue.

1 - Click on extensions panel

2 - Search for vscode-icons and click on it

3 - Click Install

4 - Restart your vscode

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons